# if statements in mysql query? LEFT join if field is equal to

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query to my database that currently gets data from a table called `feed` I am then getting the posterid and joining it with the matching userid in my `users` table.

Basically, I have 2 types of users - 1) person or 2) a company / Network (info contained in table called `networks`

my table looks like this (feed)

```
id| posterid| post_content| type |

 1    9        Hello!        user

 2    10293    Meow!         Network
```

My query is

```
$feed= $this->db->query("SELECT *,
            users.*
    FROM (`feed`)
    LEFT JOIN users ON users.userID = feed.posterid

");
```

My question is- in the query is there a way to check the type, if its type is set to user then join the users table or if its network to then join the networks table instead?

Not sure if this is an actual thing.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this but you need to list the columns that you want.  SQL queries return a fixed list of columns.  Something like:

```
SELECT f.*, u.*, n.*
FROM feed f LEFT JOIN
     users u
     ON u.userID = f.posterid AND type = 'user' LEFT JOIN
     networks n
     ON n.networkID = f.posterid AND type = 'network;
```

The columns from the "other" table are `NULL`.  You should list the columns out explicitly.  And for common columns, you might want to use `COALESCE()`.